# text input (seperated by comma) mysql input as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search, tags

I have a form where I am trying to implement a tag system.

It is just an:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

with values separated by commas.

```
e.g. "John,Mary,Ben,Steven,George"
```

(The list can be as long as the user wants it to be.)

I want to take that list and insert it into my database as an array (where users can add more tags later if they want). I suppose it doesn't have to be an array, that is just what seems will work best.

So, my question is how to take that list, turn it into an array, echo the array (values separated by commas), add more values later, and make the array searchable for other users. I know this question seems elementary, but no matter how much reading I do, I just can't seem to wrap my brain around how it all works. Once I think I have it figured out, something goes wrong. A simple example would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Here's what I got so far:

```
$DBCONNECT
$artisttags = $info['artisttags'];
$full_name = $info['full_name'];
$tel = $info['tel'];
$mainint = $info['maininst'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $tags = $_POST['tags'];
  if($artisttags == NULL) {
    $artisttagsarray = array($full_name, $tel, $maininst);
    array_push($artisttagsarray,$tags);
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET artisttags='$artisttagsarray' WHERE id='$id'");
    print_r($artisttagsarray); //to see if I did it right
    die();
  } else {
    array_push($artisttags,$tags);  
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET artisttags='$artisttags' WHERE id='$id'");
    echo $tags;
    echo " <br/>";
    echo $artisttags;
    die();
    }
}
```

Comment: well you can: save it to the database as a string. and when the user where to add more tags then when you retrieve the data you use explode to seperate them by comma and store them in an array and there you add the other tag as an array, then when saving it back to the database you implode it to combine them and separate them by comma.

Comment: Great! I will give that a try. I think that sounds great.

Comment: Don't do that. If you want to work with the data, make sure it's normalized. Serializing an array and saving it in one field will break even the 1st normal form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table, let's call it "tags":

```
tags
- userid
- artisttag
```

Each user may have multiple rows in this table (with one different tag on each row). When querying you use a `JOIN` operation to combine the two tables. For example:

```
SELECT username, artisttag
FROM users, tags
WHERE users.userid = tags.userid
AND   users.userid = 4711
```

This will give you all information about the user with id `4711`.

Relational database systems are built for this type of work so it will not waste space and performance. In fact, this is the optimal way of doing it if you want to be able to search the tags.

Comment: That's good to know. I hadn't thought about making a new database. 

I think that will work great!

Comment: I recommend you to pick up a book on the subject of database design because this is really important. People often struggle to understand joins and normalization, and write horrible code when trying to hack their way around these important concepts.

Comment: You can have all the tags in one text field in the HTML form and `explode` it in PHP.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Any book suggestions?

Comment: I've only read Swedish books on the subject unfortunately, but there should be lots of them out there. Some native-English-speakers may be able to help you :-) Don't expect to grasp all the concepts at once - take your time learning this!